# Trouble building node ibm_db package with Electron

Tags: node.js, db2, electron

I am attempting to build ibm_db for use in an electron app.

Build environment is windows 7, 64 bit, using MSVS 2015.

Base Node version is 4.2.6, Electron version 0.35.4 (ibm_db doesn't work with Node 5.x on windows 7, and this is the most recent elctron version using 4.x).

I have installed the CLI drivers for ibm data server client v 10.5

Building with node-gyp gives me the following error output:

```
C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db>node-gyp rebuild --target=0.35.4 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --msvs_version=2015
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.2.1
gyp info using node@4.2.6 | win32 | x64
gyp info spawn C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\python.EXE
gyp info spawn args [ 'C:\\Users\\my-user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
gyp info spawn args   '-G',
gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\my-user\\Node\\sql_gui_test\\node_modules\\ibm_db\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\my-user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\my-user\\.node-gyp\\0.35.4\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\my-user\\.node-gyp\\0.35.4',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\my-user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\my-user\\Node\\sql_gui_test\\node_modules\\ibm_db',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\my-user\\Node\\sql_gui_test\\node_modules\\ibm_db\\build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe
gyp info spawn args [ 'build/binding.sln',
gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64' ]
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  odbc.cpp
  odbc_connection.cpp
..\src\odbc.cpp(835): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'SQLINTEGER' to 'SQLSMALLINT', possible loss of data [C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db\build\odbc_bindings.vcxproj]
  odbc_statement.cpp
..\src\odbc_connection.cpp(115): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'intptr_t' to 'SQLHENV' [C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db\build\odbc_bindings.vcxproj]
  ..\src\odbc_connection.cpp(115): note: Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
..\src\odbc_connection.cpp(116): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'intptr_t' to 'SQLHDBC' [C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db\build\odbc_bindings.vcxproj]
  ..\src\odbc_connection.cpp(116): note: Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
  odbc_result.cpp
..\src\odbc_statement.cpp(122): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'intptr_t' to 'SQLHENV' [C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db\build\odbc_bindings.vcxproj]
  ..\src\odbc_statement.cpp(122): note: Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
..\src\odbc_statement.cpp(123): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'intptr_t' to 'SQLHDBC' [C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db\build\odbc_bindings.vcxproj]
  ..\src\odbc_statement.cpp(123): note: Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
..\src\odbc_statement.cpp(124): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'intptr_t' to 'SQLHSTMT' [C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db\build\odbc_bindings.vcxproj]
  ..\src\odbc_statement.cpp(124): note: Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
  dynodbc.cpp
..\src\odbc_result.cpp(101): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'intptr_t' to 'SQLHENV' [C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db\build\odbc_bindings.vcxproj]
  ..\src\odbc_result.cpp(101): note: Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
..\src\odbc_result.cpp(102): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'intptr_t' to 'SQLHDBC' [C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db\build\odbc_bindings.vcxproj]
  ..\src\odbc_result.cpp(102): note: Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
..\src\odbc_result.cpp(103): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'intptr_t' to 'SQLHSTMT' [C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db\build\odbc_bindings.vcxproj]
  ..\src\odbc_result.cpp(103): note: Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\my-user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--target=0.35.4" "--arch=x64" "--dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell" "" "--msvs_version=2015"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
C:\Users\my-user\Node\sql_gui_test\node_modules\ibm_db>
```

Any thoughts?

--EDIT--

Additional info -

I've discovered that if I steal the OSX clidriver files, and build with those isntead, I don't get the build error.

The module doesn't actually function though, it fails with a "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error" prior to successfully establishing a when attempting to connect with a known valid connection string.

I guess that's sort of expected.

I then proceeded to replace all of the include files using the ones from my from my IBM\SQLLIB directory, one at a time and kept rebuilding until I could reproduce the build error.

It kept up precisely the same behavior until I finally got around to replacing "sqlsystem.h", which caused the build error to issue again.

I tried diffing both sqlsystem.h files to see if there was anything that made sense, but, alas, my C++ knowledge is basically nil, so, I'm at a loss as to explain any of this.

Comment: Does it work if you build it for regular Node v4 x64 with `--msvs_version=2015`?

Comment: npm install results in a functional installation on vanilla Node 4.2.6, rebuilding gives the same error. 
If I point the package at the files downloaded by IBM_db during install, instead of the driver files downloaded for ibm data server client, I get an error about a missing sqlcli1.h file, which is indeed not present. This behavior again is identical between building for vanilla Node and building for electron.

I suspect there is a gyp build flag I'm missing, or I've somehow got the wrong drivers installed, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to investigate further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out!

This package is obnoxiously difficult to build on win32 -

See the following [issue](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/issues/96).

Here is how I solved it:

**NOTE:** In the proceeding instructions, for best results, always use the fully qualified path for any directory listed.

1. Navigate to:  `$projectDir/node_modules/ibm_db`
2. Run: `node-gyp clean`
3. Set the `IBM_DB_HOME` environment variable to `$projectDir/node_modules/ibm_db/installer/clidriver`
4. Run: `node-gyp configure --target=0.35.4 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --msvs_version=2015 --IS_DOWNLOADED=true`
5. This will make a .vcxproj xml file in your `~./ibm_db/Build/` directory. You will need to manually edit this file to remove any reference to 'odbc32.lib'
6. You now need to download the header files for the linux (yes, really) 64bit DB2 drivers [link](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/linuxx64_odbc_cli.tar.gz)
7. Inside that tar.gz file is an `clidriver/include/` directory. Copy that entire 'include' folder, and paste it into `$projectDir/installer/clidriver/` (so you now have the folder `$projectDir/installer/clidriver/include`)
8. Now, from your `$projectDir/node_modules/ibm_db` directory, run: `msbuild build/binding.sln /nologo /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64`

**NOTE:** For whatever reason, msbuild wasn't aliased properly on my machine, so the command I actually had to run was: 
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" build/binding.sln /nologo /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64` 
- Your mileage may vary.

9. Ta-da! Assuming you didn't get any nasty build errors, you've now finally finished building the ibm_db package for use with Electron.